# Appium Error Message - [WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response:

Tags: java, selenium, proxy, appium

Most of the applicaiton is using proxy, so I have configued proxy details in system environment variable. Appium is thowing below error message after configured proxy in environment variable. Appium is running successfully if i removed from proxy from environment variable but all other application is not working because ofproxy is removed. So I want to bypass proxy while running appium alone. Please let me know how to bypass proxy while running appium ?

Tools : Appium, Java, Selenium, iOS Mobile Testing

Error Message

[image]